# Akka on kubernetes k8s. Scheduling of downed unreachable nodes

Tags: kubernetes, akka, akka-cluster

Running an Akka cluster on k8s and it is using a downing strategy (let’s say Autodowning), so in the case where a node goes unreachable the container which went unreachable exits. The problem is that this node went unreachable because of a network issue/ issue with the platform provided by k8s and as such the entire pod should be restarted and scheduled onto a new healthy k8s node. Because scheduling can take some time we only want to reschedule the container onto a new pod on a new node if unreachability is the cause of the failure. Is there any way to propagate failure messages to the parent in k8s like use an exit code to make the decision of when to restart the container and when to delete the pod.

Comment: I'd add that auto-downing is basically suicide; especially in an elastic environment like K8. Don't worry about the cause of the failure. Use a real downing provider and just let K8 do it's thing via normal health checks (provided by Akka Management by default).

Answer (score 1):

> Because scheduling can take some time we only want to reschedule the container onto a new pod on a new node if unreachability is the cause of the failure.

Kubernetes manages all scheduling and health checks for you.

> Is there any way to propagate failure messages to the parent in Kubernetes like use an exit code

Kubernetes creates [events](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-events-explained) for some events, or you can *watch* the API for changes on Pods.

> to make the decision of when to restart the container and when to delete the pod.

Kubernetes manages restart, scheduling and eviction of Pods.